# React Hooks infinite loop with Array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

I'm having an infinite loop when I assign an array to a state in a useEffect hook in React and I'm not sure why as I'm adding the state `series` as a dependency.

```
const [series, setSeries] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  setSeries([1, 2, 3, 4]);
}, [series]);
```

The same code with a string doesn't create an infinite loop

```
const [series, setSeries] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  setSeries('No Infinite Loop');
}, [series]);
```

Comment: `'No Infinite Loop' === 'No Infinite Loop'` will always be true, so the dependency doesn't see a reference change, and thus no looping. When using an array though, the infinite loop is caused my placing the very state you update in the dependency array with no conditional test on it to keep it from looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React does shallow equality check when it comes to state, unless defined otherwise.
When you do this `setSeries([1, 2, 3, 4]);`, you create the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]` every single time this effect is called, and since your `useEffect` depends on `series`, it will be called infinitly.

On the other hand, shallow comparing of the strings will not cause infinite loop as they are "shallow equal".

Answer (score 3):

you have added series depandancy in hooks and you'r updating series so whenever series update that hook is called . so, it is goes into infinite .

```
const [series, setSeries] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  setSeries([1, 2, 3, 4]);
}, []);
```

Comment: @Charles de Dreuille if this does ans your que than please do it as marked so can close this que .

Answer (score 1):

`[1,2,3]!==[1,2,3]` while `"123"==="123"` when you set the array as a dependency and use THAT array as a state, the array "change" everything when `setSeries` which in turn trigger render in turn trigger `useEffect` which in turn trigger `setSeries` so on and so forth